# Pymysql docker: Connection refused to mysql docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, pymysql

I have this `docker-compose.yml`:

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - database

  database:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=data
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

This is the connection file:

**db.py**

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

#get enviroment
load_dotenv()

DB_ENGINE = os.getenv('DB_ENGINE')
DB_USER = os.getenv('DB_USER')
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
DB_HOST = os.getenv('DB_HOST')
DB_NAME = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

# connect to data base
engine = create_engine('{0}://{1}:{2}@{3}/{4}'.format(DB_ENGINE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_NAME),
    pool_pre_ping=True)

meta = MetaData()
connection = engine.connect()
```

This is the `.env` file:

```
#DB credentials
DB_HOST=database
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_NAME=data
DB_ENGINE=mysql+pymysql
```

And this is my dockerfile:

**dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9.12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

#Dependencies
RUN pip install -r requeriments.txt

CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--reload"]
```

Now, when I run it, I get the next error:

```bash
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

But when I run my python app outside of a container to mysql docker, the connection is successfully and the python program works. Only when I put python app into a container too is when the connection is refused.

I want that my program runs into a container.

Comment: The `links:` block is only relevant to an obsolete Docker networking mode, and you can (and should) delete it with no consequences to your application.  Does deleting it help at all?  If you run `docker-compose up -d`, wait a minute or so, and run it a second time, does it work the second time?

Comment: Even if i don't use a docker-compose file, but creating a docker to everyone one by one (e.g. ```docker build <python image>```, then ```docker run <python image>```, and then ```docker run mysql``` (setting up correctly env, network, and etc)). Connection is also refused.

Comment: Did the `mysql` container actually start? Check its logs.

Comment: are you able to connect MySQL with MySQL client?